# Meta Query Filter by Tag Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have multiple pages, and in each page is a custom field which is named 'country'.

In the 'country' field I have this value 'uk, usa, brazil'.

What I'm wanting to do is display posts on the page which have the tags I have listed in the custom field 'country' (In this case show posts which has any of the tags 'uk', 'usa' and 'brazil').

I have the following code, but I don't know how to manipulate it to do the above?

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),  // YOUR POST TYPE
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'country',  
            'value'     => $your_country,  // THE COUNTRY TO SEARCH
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',  // TO SEARCH THIS COUNTRY IN YOUR COMMA SEPERATED STRING
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It seems to just be filtering for a single value?

Any help to achieve the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd setup a custom taxonomy to create another version of 'tags' called 'country', then you can do a taxonomy query instead.

See 'Custom Post Type UI' for an easy interface to create a custom taxonomy.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
```

1. Install the CPT UI (plugin above).
2. Goto ‘Add / Edit Taxonomies’ in the menu. Add ‘Country’ as a taxonomy. Attach that to your ‘post’ post_type and 'page'.
3. Tag the pages (used to show the posts), and the 'posts' with your country tags.

You can then use the custom wp_query in a page template, to show the posts, tagged with the country tag.

To grab the ID's of the country terms, associated with your page:

$countryTerms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'country', array("fields" => "ids"));

Then change your Query arguments to gather the posts, tagged with the country.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $countryTerms
        ),
    ),
);
```

If you want to stick to a meta field, try changing your 'TYPE' value to 'NUMERIC'.

Comment: Sorry - just read through the plugin itself, I would still need it to be put through tags and not a custom taxonomy, will the bottom half of your answer be able to do this?

Comment: @Jonathan sorry you've lost me? Assume you've sorted a solution from the accepted answer?

Comment: Still a bit confused, I'm not wanting to create a custom post type. What I'm trying to do is have a custom field on a page which holds the tags I'm wanting to filter the posts on the page by. I gave you the answer as you took time and thought to write it :)

Comment: @Jonathan Use the plugin to add a custom taxonomy, not a post_type. Think this should work... Install the CPT UI (plugin above), goto ‘Add / Edit Taxonomies’ in the menu. Add ‘Country’ as a taxonomy. Attach that to your ‘post’ post_type and 'page'. Tag the pages (used to show the posts), and the 'posts' with your country tags. You can then use the custom wp_query in a page template, to show the posts, tagged with the country tag.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me (bit of a WP noob!) would you be able to edit your answer so if anyone else is having trouble they can up vote you :)