# Create new field with value separet with comma

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I am selecting multiple values ​​that I export from google sheet.

I need to make them independent of filtering them in ACF so that they can be filtered separately.

I show code that I'm trying to use in functions.php but I do not know where I'm wrong:

```
$value=get_field('location'); //location is my custom field that I am exporting from google sheet
$arrFields= explode(", ",$value); 
if( $value)
{ 
foreach($arrFields as $v){ echo $v.'<br>'; }; 
}
```

Meta Keys Select will be automatically modified? this is what the filter takes

thanks!!

Comment: what is the values of these variables `$value` and `$arrFields` ?

Comment: here is my solution. Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773745/meta-query-filter-by-tag-wordpress thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking whether it is array or not

```
$value=get_field('location'); 
$arrFields= explode(", ",$value); 
if( is_array($arrFields))
{ 
   foreach($arrFields as $k=>$v)
   { 
       echo $k.'- '.$v.'<br>'; 
   }
}
```

Comment: hi! 
I get the following error in the line:` echo $ k .'- '. $ v.' <br> ';` Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by. 
I found that I have to add a function, can it be? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use implode instead of foreach
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment. I want to convert a metadata with a separated text with comma (Paris, Madrid), in separate texts, to be able to filter it individually.